# how to populate selected items from one list box to another on a button click action?

Tags: c#, .net, html

I have two list boxes L1 and L2. Now on a button click method i have to move the selected items in L1 to L2 and Items in L1 should get Deleted.

```
  protected void Btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sel = LB1.SelectedValue;

        List<string> ab = new List<string>();

        ab.Add(sel);

        L2.Text = Convert.ToString(ab.Count);

        for(int i =0; i < ab.Count ; i++)
        {
            string c = ab[i];
            LB2.Items.Add(c);


        }
```

Comment: code looks fine , what is your problem here?

Comment: nope, the items in the listbox1 should get deleted when they move to listbox2.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove the `SelectedItem` from the `ListBox1`

add the following statement at the end of your function:

```
LB1.Items.Remove(LB1.SelectedValue);
```

**Complete Code:**

```
protected void Btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sel = LB1.SelectedValue;

    List<string> ab = new List<string>();

    ab.Add(sel);

    L2.Text = Convert.ToString(ab.Count);

    for(int i =0; i < ab.Count ; i++)
    {
        string c = ab[i];
        LB2.Items.Add(c);
    }

   LB1.Items.Remove(LB1.SelectedValue);//Add This to remove selected item from ListBox1
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
protected void Btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ListItem> itemList = new List<ListItem>();
    if (LB1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < LB1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (LB1.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                if (!itemList.Contains(LB1.Items[i]))
                {
                    itemList.Add(LB1.Items[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < itemList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!LB2.Items.Contains(itemList[i]))
            {
                LB2.Items.Add(itemList[i]);
            }
            LB1.Items.Remove(itemList[i]);
        }
        LB2.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```